# Angular 5, rxjs- wait for observable to finish only if it is in a middle of a run before running another process

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a timer in my main component of 3 seconds. inside the timer I perform http call-

```
    constructor(){
          this.timer = timer(3000, 3000);
          this.timerObservable = this.timer.subscribe(x => {
              this.http.get(URL).subscribe(()=>{
              //DO SOMETHING
              });
          });

     }
```

In another component I have a button that suppose to perform a different http call, pressing on the button invoke the sumbit function-

```
        submit(){
            this.http.get("/sumbitForm").subscribe(()=> {
              //DO SOMETHING
             })
         }
```

When a user clicks on the button, if the timer is in process (the http inside of it was called and not resolved yet) I want to wait before I perform the http call on the button until it resolved, but if the timer is not in process  (the time from the previous call did not passed yet) I want to execute it immediately.

I think that forkJoin and concat is not relevant here (this is a timer and not a 'regular' subscription that I want to wait to its execution either way) and I could not find a pretty way to do it, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to share some information between your two components, i.e. when the polling request is in progress and when it isn't. You should use a Service for this. It's also always good practice to move your http request logic to a Service instead of using the HttpClient directly in the component. This allows you to do your general error handling in one place. 
Let's call this Service ApiService.

#### ApiService

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiService {
  // Use a BehaviorSubject to notify listeners about ongoing polling requests.
  // A BahaviorSubject always has a current value that late subscribers will 
  // receive immediately upon subscribing
  private pollRequestInProgress = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  // Share this BehaviorSubject as an Observable
  public pollRequestInProgress$ = pollRequestInProgress.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)

  doPoll(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return interval(3000).pipe( // interval(3000) is equivalent to timer(3000, 3000)
      tap(_ => pollRequestInProgress.next(true)), // notify that a poll request is about to happen
      switchMap(_ => this.http.get(url)), // do your poll request
      tap(_ => pollRequestInProgress.next(false)) // notify that your poll request ended
    );
  }
}
```

#### MainComponent

This is the Component where you want to start your polling from.

```ts
private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

// move logic to ngOnInit instead of constructor
ngOnInit() {
  // subscribe and thereby start the polling
  this.apiService.doPoll(URL).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(pollResponse => {
      //DO SOMETHING
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // unsubscribe when the Component gets destroyed.
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

#### FeatureComponent

This is the Component where you want to perform a http request when you click a button.

```ts
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private apiService: apiService) {}

submit() {
  // Listen to whether a polling request is currently in progress.
  // We will immediately receive a value upon subscribing here, because we used 
  // a BehaviorSubject as the underlying source.
  this.apiService.pollRequestInProgress$.pipe(
    // Emit the first item that tells you that no polling request is in progress.
    // i.e. let the first 'requestInProgress === false' through but not any 
    // other items before or after.
    first(requestInProgress => !requestInProgress),
    // If no polling request is in progress, switch to the http request you want 
    // to perform
    switchMap(this.http.get("/sumbitForm")) // <-- consider moving this http.get to your ApiService aswell
  ).subscribe(httpResponse => {
    // you've got your http response here
  });
  // you don't have to unsubscribe here as first and http.get both complete 
  // and thus unsubscribe automatically
}
```

Check out a simple example of the code logic above here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-t4hjcr

Comment: great, thanks! but does the http in "FeatureComponent" will happen also if the button is pressed before 3000 ms have passed? or will it wait to the first "doingPollRequest.next(true)"?

Comment: And what is the purpose of "requestInProgress" in the submit?

Comment: @danda yes, the http request is executed immediately if the button gets clicked and there is no polling request going on. You can see that behavior in the stackblitz I posted. `requestInProgress` is the value from the `doingPollRequest$` Observable that tells you whether a polling request is currently ongoing and if so will wait with the execution of the http request until the polling request finished.

Comment: @danda `first` is like a filter. It lets the **first** item through that matches the given predicate and then completes. So items that don't match the predicate or later items are discarded. I added some more explanations to my code. Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, yes it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Subject

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CallService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    timerCompleted() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    checkTimer(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

The app component uses the call service to subscribe to timer complete and make them available to the app component template.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { CallService } from './_services/index';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private callService: CallService) {

        this.subscription = this.callService.checkTimer().subscribe(() => { 
           // call your api after timer complete
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

add below code in your timer

```
this.timer = timer(3000, 3000);
        this.timerObservable = this.timer.subscribe(x => {
           this.http.get(URL).subscribe(()=>{
               this.callService.timerCompleted();
           });
        });
```

For more reference you can check http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: Thanks! do you mean that I need to call  timerCompleted() instead of clearMessage() inside the subscription in the timer? and another question- does this.callService.checkTimer().subscribe will be performed if the timer did not executed (because only timeCompleted emits an event)

Comment: Yes you need to call timerCompleted() and checkTimer() will not subscribe until you emit timeCompleted() event

Comment: But I need that my http will be called also when the timer isn't get called yet (therefore not event emitted), that is my main problem.

Comment: then you need to show your whole code, in which scenario your timer is called and in which scenario it is not called.

Comment: As your timer is in constructor, it will be called always for 3 seconds.

Comment: right. this is the purpose.each 3 seconds it will be called until I destroy it in ngOnDestroy

Comment: As your timer is called everytime  this.callService.timerCompleted(); will also be called everytime.

Comment: correct, but because of this I think that the solution should be different. I just want to know in the button if I am in the middle of the timer, and if so wait. if not- execute the http immediately.

Comment: But you will be always in the timer, as the timer will be continously on for 3 secs

Comment: Sorry, that was only for the example, in live it will be every 30 seconds..

Comment: Yes but timer is a continuous process, it will be always in every 30 seconds. So when ever you check the timer is on then it will be on every time until we unsubscribe it.

Comment: Correct, I unscribe it in ngOnDestroy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188283/discussion-between-kajol-chaudhary-and-danda).